# What's more appropriate when speaking of habits: "do", "do it" or "do so"?

Tags: word-choice

I think this is a very basic grammar question, but I'm stuck with how I should continue the sentences. Could someone explain it?

> 1. In Japan, I've never shopped at a wholesale store, but I **did/did it/did so** a lot in the States.
> 2. I used to read books almost everyday, but now I **do/do it/do so** only once a week.

About the sentence 2, I know that I can say, "but now only once a week." But I'd like to know which is the best if I give a full sentence.

Comment: I'd be writing the first one as: "In Japan, I've never shopped at a wholesale store, but I **used to** a lot *(back?)* in the States."

Comment: I guess every options in both the sentences are correct.

Comment: I think all of them are equally valid. You could also repeat the verb, as another valid option: _I used to read books almost everyday, but now I **read** only once a week; In Japan, I've never shopped at a wholesale store, but I **shopped wholesale** a lot in the States._

Comment: All of them are correct. Grammatically...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The selection in these sentences is purely a style choice; all are correct. **did so** is a tiny bit more formal, and I personally would use **did it** only when the action is in noun form (e.g., *I used to enjoy reading*), but there's nothing wrong in grammar or usage in any of the choices.